# Right to left display minute scale using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created minute scale its working fine for me but now i am facing problem to display my scale instead of left to right i want to display my minute right to left .

can any one suggest me what i am doing wrong and where i need to change i really appreciate for that if any one help me in that ...here below i am giving my fiddle link you can check my whole code here...

http://jsfiddle.net/sam140/n4qLv

```
$(function() {
    // Build "dynamic" rulers by adding items
    $(".ruler[data-items]").each(function() {
        var ruler = $(this).empty(),
            len = Number(ruler.attr("data-items")) || 0,
            item = $(document.createElement("li")),
            circel= $(document.createElement("div")),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           if(i%5==0)
           {
               ruler.append(item.clone().text(i + 1).addClass("sample"));
               //$(item).css("height","20px")
           } else {
               ruler.append(item.clone().text("").css('height','22px'));   
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can check whole code here...http://jsfiddle.net/sam140/n4qLv/

Comment: `ruler.prepend` instead of `ruler.append` at line 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/n4qLv/1/

`ruler.prepend` instead of `ruler.append` at line 12 and 17